# Why the statements in the function are returning null?

Tags: javascript, function, indexing, onchange, getelementbyid

The below code i have written to apply color on different note but the issue is these statements are giving me null when i `console log` them which i don't understand Why?
As they are working quite fine.

Here is the code use to design notes:

```
function showNote2() {
    console.log("Show");
    let note = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if(note == null){
        noteData = []
        // message.innerText = "Please Add a Note"
    }
    else{
        noteData = JSON.parse(note);
    };
    let showBox = "";
    let color1 = "";
    noteData.forEach(function show(element, index) {
        // localStorage.setItem(`clr${index}`, color)
        color1 = localStorage.getItem(`clr${index}`);
        // console.log(color1)
        showBox += `<div class="noteCard my-2 mx-2 card" id="cardID" style="width: 18rem;">
        <select id="mySelect${index}" class="clr-btn" style="text-align:center" onchange="changeColor(${index})">
        <option id="bckgrnd-clr" value="white">Background Color</option>
        <option id="clrR" value="Red">Red</option>
        <option id="clrG" value="Green">Green</option>
        <option  id="clrB" value="Blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
                <div class="card-body" id="card${index}" style="background-color:${color1}">
                  <h5 class="cardtitle">Note
                  ${index + 1}
                  </h5>
                  <p class="card-text"> 
                  ${element}
                  </p>
                  <button id="${index}" onclick="deleteNote(this.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</a>
                </div>
              </div>   `
            });

    console.log(color1)    
              let showNote3 = document.getElementById("notes2");
              if(noteData.length != 0){
                  showNote3.innerHTML = showBox;
              }else{
                  showNote3.innerHTML = "Please add a Note"
              };
            //   Color()
            //   changeColor()
            
        };
```

And here is the code which gives option to choose different color for different notes:

```
let clrstore;
function changeColor(index) {
    console.log("Change");
    let note = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    if(note != null ){
        // let showNote3 = document.getElementById(`card4${index}`);
        // console.log(showNote3);
        let diffColorApply = document.getElementById(`card${index}`);
        console.log(diffColorApply);
        let elm1 = document.getElementById(`mySelect${index}`);
        console.log(elm1);
        let color = elm1.options[elm1.selectedIndex].value;
        colorApply.style.backgroundColor = color;
        clrstore = localStorage.setItem(`clr${index}`, color)
    }
    else{
        `Note is Empty`;
    }
}
```

`console.log(diffColorApply);` and `console.log(elm1);` returns `null` which is causing issue in executing another function.
Also `let color = elm1.options[elm1.selectedIndex].value;` this error reading `options`
Don't know Why?
As it is working quite fine.

Comment: `color1` should be a local variable in the `forEach()` callback function. Otherwise, all the callback functions are using the variable from the same scope.

Comment: You have a typo: `card4${index}` should be `card${index}`

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. You shouldn't use the same `id="cardID"` and `id="clrR"` in every card.

Comment: So either leave out the IDs if they're not really needed, or add `${index}` to all of them.

Comment: FYI, `elm1.options[elm1.selectedIndex].value` can be simplified to just `elm1.value`

Comment: `elm1.value` also gives the error, `error reading "null" `
This the issue `options` and `value` both return `null` but still color is applied
Here is the code-pen

Comment: https://codepen.io/heck_coding/pen/vYevBVj

Comment: I'm not getting any error in the codepen

Comment: `showNote3` which is using `card4{index}` i am not using. I have already commented it out. I am using `DiffColorApply` which container `card${Index}` id

Comment: console.log these `console.log(diffColorApply)` and `console.log(elm1)`
then let me know

Comment: also `console.log color`

Comment: When I select from the menu it logs `Change` then `<div class="card-body" id="card1" style="background-color: green;">...</div>` then `<select id="mySelect1" class="clr-btn" style="text-align:center" onchange="changeColor(1)">...</select>`

Comment: Please post the code here using a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) instead of a link to codepen.

Comment: It's correctly changing the background color when I select from the dropdown.